# StructureMap: Choose concrete type of nested dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, constructor-injection

Calculators:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Calculate(int a, int b);
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    private readonly ICalculatorStrategy _calculatorStrategy;

    public Calculator(ICalculatorStrategy calculatorStrategy)
    {
        _calculatorStrategy = calculatorStrategy;
    }

    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return _calculatorStrategy.Calculate(a, b);
    }
}
```

Calculator stragies:

```
public interface ICalculatorStrategy
{
    int Calculate(int a, int b);
}

public class AdditionCalculator : ICalculatorStrategy
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

public class MultiplyCalculator : ICalculatorStrategy
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Calculator usages:

```
public class CalculatorUsageOne
{
    private readonly ICalculator _calculator;

    public CalculatorUsageOne(ICalculator calculator)
    {
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_calculator.Calculate(6, 5));
    }
}

public class CalculatorUsageTwo
{
    private readonly ICalculator _calculator;

    public CalculatorUsageTwo(ICalculator calculator)
    {
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_calculator.Calculate(6, 5));
    }
}
```

Structuremap Registry:

```
public class DependencyRegistry : Registry
{
    public DependencyRegistry()
    {
        For<ICalculatorStrategy>().Use<AdditionCalculator>().Named("Addition");
        For<ICalculatorStrategy>().Use<MultiplyCalculator>().Named("Multiply");
        For<ICalculator>().Use<Calculator.Calculator>();
    }
}
```

For CalculatorUsageOne I want to add the numbers (use **AdditionCalculator**).
For CalculatorUsageTwo I want to multiply the numbers (use **MultiplyCalculator**).

How do I achieve this with StructureMap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
For<CalculatorUsageOne>().Use<CalculatorUsageOne>()
    .Ctor<ICalculator>().Is<Calculator.Calculator>(
        x => x.Ctor<ICalculatorStrategy>().Is<AdditionCalculator>()
    );
For<CalculatorUsageTwo>().Use<CalculatorUsageTwo>()
    .Ctor<ICalculator>().Is<Calculator.Calculator>(
        x => x.Ctor<ICalculatorStrategy>().Is<MultiplyCalculator>()
    );
```

You can nest your objects graph configurations as deep as you need. Anyway, I would think about using generics here to show the dependencies in more explicit way.

**edit about generics:**

Whether using generics is a good idea here depends from your scenario. If you didn't specified the concrete dependencies for your `CalculatorUsages` on purpose and that's your goal to have it strategy-agnostic, your solution seems to be the best.

But if you just need to have common implementation of `Calculator` in "middle layer", you can specify `Calculator`'s dependency in generic parameter to make it explicit. Maybe it's not the best use case here, but it can go somehow like this:

```
public class CalculatorUsageOne
{
    public CalculatorUsageOne(ICalculator<AdditionCalculator> calculator)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Calculator<T> where T : ICalculatorStrategy
{
    public Calculator(T strategy)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and register it like this:

```
For(typeof(ICalculator<>).Use(typeof(Calculator<>);
```

This will tell StructureMap to pass any generic parameter for requested `ICalculator` to `Calculator` ([open generics](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/01/13/open-generic-types-in-structuremap/)), which then instantiates the strategy objects in constructor.

Alternatively, you can use [marker interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) instead of generics, but once again, it all depends from your particular scenario and it may be that the simplest solution from very beginning fits best.

Comment: @A. "Anyway, I would think about using generics here to show the dependencies in more explicit way." How would this looks like?

Comment: @Rookian, I've edited my answer with some thoughts about generics.

Comment: @A. How would I test ICalulator<AdditionCalculator>? Is it still possible at all or how would I fake it?

Comment: Wheh testing `CalculatorUsage`, `ICalculator<AdditionCalculator>` is still an interface that can be mocked like any other. When testing `ICalculator<T>`, you can mock `ICalculatorStrategy` and test `ICalculator<FakeCalculatorStrategy>`

Answer (score 1):

One method is to define the dependency when getting an instance using the `With` method.

```
var additionStrategy = ObjectFactory
                            .GetNamedInstance<ICalculatorStrategy>("Addition");
var c1 = ObjectFactory.With(additionStrategy).GetInstance<CalculatorUsageOne>();
```

The only other way I can think of is providing the isntances as constructor arguments when registering the types. I can provide an example tomorrow.