# How DI frameworks resolve dependency for same Interface with multiple configuration?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap3

Consider below code sample:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   void SetName(string name);
   string GetName();
}

public class MyInterfaceImplementor1 : IMyInterface
{
   protected string Name { set; get; }

   public void SetName(string name)
   {
      this.Name = name;
   }

   public virtual string GetName()
   {
      return this.Name;
   }
}

public class MyInterfaceImplementor2 : MyInterfaceImplementor1
{
   public override string GetName()
   {
      return String.Format("Hello! {0}", base.Name);
   }
}
```

And the DI configuration for this: (**StructureMap** code snippet provided)

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x => 
{
   x.For<IMyInterface>()
    .Use<MyInterfaceImplementor1>();
});

ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
   x.For<IMyInterface>()
    .Use<MyInterfaceImplementor2>();
});
```

Say, in my code, at some point I am using **MyInterfaceImplementor1** and at some other point, I use **MyInterfaceImplementor2**. My question is, how the DI framework (StructureMap or any other) will resolve the above configuration? Also, how will it determine, where to return an instance of **MyInterfaceImplementor1** and when the same of **MyInterfaceImplementor2**? OR Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The one I use needs help: an @Qualifier(name = "x") annotation and an alias does trick.

Comment: @duffymo, I didn't understand what you meant? Can you give an example please? Thanks.

Comment: I did give an example.  I use Spring.

Answer (score 2):

In your case StructureMap will resolve *MyInterfaceImplementor2*. StructureMap stores all registrations but resolves the last one registered with *Use()* method.

### Nomenclature

**Plugin type** - type that is to be injected, in most of the cases it is an interface but SM resolves also concrete types (even if you haven't registered them)

**Plugged/concrete type** - implementation of plugin type

```
c.For<IPluginType>().Use<ConcreteType>();
```

Generally in SM there are 2 types of manual registration. You can register dependencies with *Add()* and *Use()* method.

What is the difference?

- *Add()* just registers concrete type in plugin family
- *Use()* registers and sets it as default registration to be used when resolving plugin type

For *Add()* there is a convention that when you have only one registration then it will be resolved. In case when there is more than one registration container would throw *StructureMapException* when trying to resolve plugin type.

csprabala answer provides good explanation how multiple implementations should be registerd within StructureMap.

When I have multiple implementations of plugin type I always register the with *Add()* method and if there is a default implementation I register it with *Use()*

Answer (score 0):

[How to map same interface to different ConcreteClasses with StructureMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992700/how-to-map-same-interface-to-different-concreteclasses-with-structuremap)

Look at the above. Most DI frameworks use hints presented in the form of names/attributes to inject the appropriate concrete classes at run time.

Look at the below to

[StructureMap: Choose concrete type of nested dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575883/structuremap-choose-concrete-type-of-nested-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it makes much sense to have multiple implementations of the same interface, but not in all cases. Always make sure that you are not violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP). Here are two cases, one where the use of multiple implementations is okay, and one where it is not.

Say for instance you have an `ILogger` abstraction with `FileLogger` and `SqlLogger` implementations. In most cases you want to log stuff to the database, but in some parts of the system, you explicitly want to log to a file instead, because the log errors in this part of the system are picked up by a different system that has no access to the database. Although you should always ask yourself [whether or not you're logging too much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915056/264697), as long as swapping the implementations doesn't affect the consumers of the `ILogger` abstraction, from perspective of the LSP, you are fine.

However, let's say your application communicates with two databases, that each have their own schema. On top of this you have an `IUnitOfWork` abstraction, that is used to communicate with the database. Based on this abstraction you implemented the `OrdersUnitOfWork` for communicating with the Orders database, and the `CrmUnitOfWork` to communicate with the CRM database. Obviously some parts of the system need to get the `OrdersUnitOfWork` to work, while others need the `CrmUnitOfWork`. If this is the case, you are breaking the LSP, since you can't simply swap the implementations without the consumers to notice. No, when supplying a consumer with the wrong implementation it will completely break, because the database schema's are completely different. This is a violation of the LSP.

So in the latter case, the problem is in the design of the application and can be fixed by giving each database its own abstraction. For instance: `IOrdersUnitOfWork` and `ICrmUnitOfWork`.

If you do this kind of registration, it completely depends on the DI library you use, whether it returns the first or the last. This is often very unintuitive, and this makes it very easy to make a configuration error because of this.

For that reason, the DI library Simple Injector does not allow these kind of registrations. The designers of Simple Injector find such API a design flaw as we explain [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections). Instead, Simple Injector forces you to make either a single registration for a given key (`IMyInterface` in your case) or register a collection of things. This prevents the confusion all together of what the library will return for you.

In case you need to determine the implementation to inject, based on its consumer, Simple Injector allows you to do [context based injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection). For instance:

```
container.Register<MyInterfaceImplementor1>();
container.Register<MyInterfaceImplementor2>();

container.RegisterWithContext<IMyInterface>(context =>
    context.ImplementationType.Namespace.Contains("Administrator")
        ? container.GetInstance<MyInterfaceImplementor1>()
        : container.GetInstance<MyInterfaceImplementor2>());
```

Here which implementation to inject is determined based on the namespace of the consumer. You can think of all kind of rules of course to determine what to inject.

Answer (score 0):

StructureMap will blow up with an exception because it will NOT try to guess which one you want if there's more than one registration -- and I stand by that decision to this day. Some of the other IoC containers will use either the first one registered or the last one registered.