# Custom resolve nested dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

Suppose the following class structure:

```
ClassA (IClassB classb, IClassC classc) : IClassA
ClassB (IClassC classc) : IClassB
ClassC1 () : IClassC
ClassC2 () : IClassC
```

Suppose I want to use `ClassC1` whenever it is used to resolve specifically `IClassA`, i.e. `container.GetInstance<IClassA>()` would return

```
new ClassA(
 new ClassB (new ClassC1()),
 new ClassC1()
)
```

Can I do something like this in StructureMap? (Ideally, something like `For<ClassA>().Nest(x => x.For<IClassC>().Use<ClassC1>())`, but anything would do.)

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6575883/1180926, but this asks for the ability to "skip: steps in the chain, thus allowing for a single declaration of `IClassC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got:

```
public interface IClassA
{
}

public interface IClassB
{
}

public interface IClassC
{
}

public class ClassA: IClassA
{
    public ClassA(IClassB classb, IClassC classc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassA");
        Console.WriteLine("  ClassB: {0}", classb.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("  ClassC: {0}", classc.GetType());
    }
}

public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    public ClassB(IClassC classc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassB");
        Console.WriteLine("  ClassC: {0}", classc.GetType());
    }
}

public class ClassC1 : IClassC
{
    public ClassC1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassC1");
    }
}

public class ClassC2 : IClassC
{
    public ClassC2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassC2");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IContainer container = ConfigureDependencies();

        container.GetInstance<IClassA>();
        container.GetInstance<IClassB>();
    }

    private static IContainer ConfigureDependencies()
    {
        return new Container(x =>
        {
            x.For<IClassA>().Use<ClassA>();
            x.For<IClassB>().Use<ClassB>();
            x.For<IClassC>().Use(z => z.RootType == typeof(ClassA) ? (IClassC) z.GetInstance<ClassC1>() : z.GetInstance<ClassC2>());
        });
    }

}
```

Concrete type of `IClassC` is determined by `RootType`.

This is output:

```
ClassC1
ClassB
  ClassC: MongodbEnumerable.ClassC1
ClassA
  ClassB: MongodbEnumerable.ClassB
  ClassC: MongodbEnumerable.ClassC1
ClassC2
ClassB
  ClassC: MongodbEnumerable.ClassC2
```

It shows that `ClassC1` was used for constructing `ClassA` and its dependencies but for constructing separate `IClassB` was used `ClassC2`.

Comment: What is `UseIfNone`doing that the ternary could not do?

Comment: @Arithmomaniac Good note!  It does nothing, I forgot to remove this line after experimenting.  I updated the answer and removed this line.